# Git submoduleを親のリポジトリと同時にコミット、プッシュしたい

Tags: git, github

質問はタイトルの通りで、現在CMSを使ってブログサイトを作成しているのですが、CMSを親リポジトリとしてそのSubmoduleにCMSにより生成されたブログ本体を保持させているのですが、サブモジュールであるブログ本体は、親モジュールであるCMSによって生成されるので、親モジュールの変更と同時にサブモジュールもコミットプッシュしたいのですが、そういったことはGitコマンドで可能でしょうか。
もしそのようなコマンドが存在しないのであれば、サブモジュールをプッシュしたあとで親モジュールをプッシュするという形になるのでしょうか。

追記

```
Pushing submodule 'public'
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Unable to push submodule 'public'
fatal: Failed to push all needed submodules!
```

public というのはサブモジュールのディレクトリ名です。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

一般的には次のような手順になると思います。

コミット: まず `git submodule foreach` を使い、各サブモジュールでの変更のステージングとコミットを行います。コミットメッセージは `-m` オプションで与えてください。

```
git submodule foreach git add -A
git submodule foreach git commit -m 'submodule commit message'
```

その後にメインモジュールのステージングとコミットを行います。

```
git add -A
git commit
```

プッシュ: `git submodule foreach git push` を使ってもよいですが、 `git push` には `--recurse-submodules=on-demand` というオプションがあり、これを利用すればメインモジュールおよび変更のあったサブモジュールのプッシュを同時に実行できます。

```
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

うまくシェルスクリプトを書けば、同一のコミットメッセージを使ってすべてのサブモジュール・メインモジュールのコミット・プッシュができると思います。工夫してみてください。

(なお `commit-msg` フックを利用する方法はうまくいきません)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
コミットまではできましたが、最後で`git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand -u origin master`を入力したとこと、エラーがでてしまいました。
`--set-upstream`をかけと言われて書きましたが、同様のエラーがでました。エラーは質問文に追記させていただきました。

Comment: `git submodule foreach git push`でできました。詳しくお教え頂ありがとうございます。